# How to configure HHVM with Nginx compiled from source?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, hhvm

I installed Nginx 1.8 (compiled from source) on Debian 7:

```
cd /opt/
sudo wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
sudo wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxzf ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
cd /opt/nginx-1.8.0/

sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --add-module=/tmp/ngx_cache_purge-2.3

sudo make && make install
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password --group nginx 

sudo wget -O init-deb.sh http://www.linode.com/docs/assets/1538-init-deb.sh
sudo mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

Than I start nginx with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

And everything works fine until now.

The problem is when I try to install HHVM it doesn't work:

```
sudo wget -O - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian wheezy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm libgmp-dev libmemcached-dev
sudo update-rc.d hhvm defaults
```

And when I finally run:

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Checking if Nginx is installed
Nginx not found
```

Any thoughts how I can install HHVM with Nginx compiled from source?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to read the script and apply its patch manually. It's hardcoded to work with the distro-supplied nginx, and assumes that it's installed in that location -- since the `deb` we provide for Debian sticks a particular script in the nginx system configuration anyways. Your manually built nginx is in a different location; the script would have no way of knowing where to find it!

[Here's the source for the `install_fastcgi.sh`](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/master/hhvm/deb/skeleton/usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh) -- the relevant bit is that it [inserts a line after `server_name` to include `hhvm.conf`](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/f077d85bcb022aada788777b4f3c7036459a53ae/hhvm/deb/skeleton/usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh#L212). You can find that `hhvm.conf` either [here](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/master/hhvm/deb/skeleton/etc/nginx/hhvm.conf) or it's probably already on your system at `/etc/nginx/hhvm.conf`.

BTW, the script really isn't that complicated. In general, a good way to figure out why something broke is to skim through it and see what it's doing :)